# Shared "SQL Server 2005 Server Project" in Visual Studio 2008 Database Edition GDR 2

Tags: sql, visual-studio, tfs

Hi after toying around with SQL Server 2005 Database projects, I have been pointed to the Visual Studio 2008 Database Edition GDR 2 extension (by our Microsoft rep), which allows for the creation of "SQL Server 2005 Server Project" projects.

As far as I understand it, this lets you create a project with all the shared objects (logins being the most useful to me) of the Dev instance.  Then when you create a "SQL Server 2005 Database Project" you can reference the "SharedDev" project, and all the objects (logins etc) will be accessible from your Database Project (say MyNorthwind).

What I don't understand is, when I'm creating my "SQL Server 2005 Server Project" SharedDev project, should I create it from Master on my Dev instance, or from the Northwind Dev instance?

Has anyone got any experience of this?  Searches at MSDN bring up really slim docs.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193425.aspx

Maybe I'm over complicating things.
Thanks for anyone who can shine a bit of light on this.

Comment: I'm interested in this - did you ever find out any more info?

Answer (score 1):

You want to create your database from the "Northwind" db not from Master.  This should result in your project containing scripts which will create the logins when you deploy.

Best resource for VSTSDB is here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsdb/threads

For what its worth: Logins are a bit tricky VSTSDB 2008.  The tool really shines with the management of the objects.